# How to rerun ScalaCheck Commands tests given a seed

Tags: command, random-seed, stateful, scalacheck, property-based-testing

I have a scalacheck `Commands` test suite. When I run it it fails in a particularly interesting way, and prints out a seed. I would like to re-run the tests with that seed.

I've tried the following:

- `sbt Test/runMain MyTest -initialSeed <the seed>`
- `Stub extends Properties { propertyWithSeed("lol", <the seed>) = MyCommands.property()` (instead of calling just `property("lol") = MyCommands.property()`)
- In `Stub extends Properties { ... }`, define a `overrideParameters(p: Test.Parameters): Test.Parameters` in which I override the initial seed parameters on `p`.

In all cases, I seem to get a new random seed.

Why is this, and how can I replay `Commands` tests with my favorite failing seed?